# Install Ubuntu Linux in an existing empty ext4 partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I am using Install Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS running from an ISO DVD.  Before running Install, Disk Utility was used to set desired partitions with logical partitions of 108 GB ext4 for Ubuntu and 20 GB for Swap and no empty space.  The option “Install Ubuntu alongside W7” asked me to free up space from 2 partitions to install Linux.  The “advanced partitioning tool” option showed all partitions, but I could not find a way to select the ext4 partition for install.  I tried deleting the ext4 partition to let the installer create it in the space freed up.  Clicking “Install Now” gave the message “No root file system is defined Please correct this from the partitioning menu”  I could not find how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using Something Else or manual install you create new partitions or change existing partitions. Click on change or + box.
You have to specify size, format and mount. If they already exist, you do not have to specify size, but still need to format to ext4 for / (root) and tell it that that partition is / as you may have other partitions like /home or others to specify also. It does not automatically know what you want to use partitions as.

Auto install works best if you only want / & swap with whatever defaults it decides. Also best to shrink Windows using Windows tools to leave unallocated space if using any of the auto install options.

Some have found the auto install with newest Ubutnu with LVM or encrypted with LVM overwrites entire drive.

Comment: Thanks to oldfred for his prompt reply.  My experience with Linux is very limited.  Although deleting the ext4 partition and then continuing did not work, deleting, restarting Install, selecting dual boot and then install did seem to do a complete install.  At the end of the install there was a message to restart so any changes to files would be saved.  Unfortunately all later starts went to W7, even the BIOS boot menu.  Booting from DVD has an option to go to a grub command line Version 1.99-21ubuntu3.10. Can this be used to start Linux?  I will need step by step instructions.

Comment: Use Boot-Repair and post link to BootInfo report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info